# How to extend Django CMS template?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I want to use a base template and then extend partial views. `extends` not working as it is not showing base markup at all.

**base.html**

```
<div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**_hello.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>Survey About Computer Programming</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Programming</h3>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <th>Main</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Option1</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Option2</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Option3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Do you love Programming?</td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="/static/survey/js/plugin.js"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: It was not pasted here but `block` is mentioned already, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put your code inside the block *content* . The extended template overwrites the blocks in the base template.

```
<div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
    {% block js_bottom %}
    {% endblock %}
```

_hello.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>Survey About Computer Programming</h2></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Programming</h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr align="center">
                    <th>Main</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Option1</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Option2</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Option3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Do you love Programming?</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
    {% endblock %}

{% block js_bottom %}
<script src="/static/survey/js/plugin.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: well, this is the answer to your question.  btw, you created a double 'container' div in your design.

Answer (score 0):

You Missed important thing whenver we are creating template like this we have to make sure every block like CSS, Content, JS must be defined proporly in base html file. And when you extends this base template then you have to framed your content as per requirement. Like if you need to put some content in the html page which extends the base html simply call as following
{% block _block_name_should_be_here %}
{% endblock %}

Block name might be like css_part , content_part , js_part which needs to be used the html page.

Comment: It is a Django CMS Plugin and all header footer already present.